# Select from Header when detail value is certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, not-exists

I am want to select a table that has a one to many relationship with a detail table. 
But I only want the rows that do not have a certain value in the detail table. In The example i do not want to select `Row1` Because it has a value of `C` in the detail table.

```
Table 1
0 |Row1
1 |Row2
2 |Row3
3 |Row4

Table2
0 |A
1 |A
2 |A
3 |A
0 |C
1 |B
2 |B
3 |B
```

**Bonus**
Can it be done with a `JOIN` ?

Comment: use NOT EXISTS and IN clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Table2 t2
                  WHERE t1.TableID = t2.TableID
                   AND  t2.Column2 = 'C')
```

Comment: Thanx, had some problem making it work because i was forgetting to compare the keys `WHERE t1.TableID = t2.TableID´